# Add registry key to multiple remote computers

Tags: powershell

I want to create a new registry key on multiple machines, but my script is not working. Can you give me some hints?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web 

$Computers = Get-Content -Path 'G:\Shares\xxx\SebaTesty\computerlist.txt'

$results = foreach ($computer in $Computers)
{
    If (test-connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)
    {
        Try
        {
            New-ItemProperty -Path "hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" -Name "ArpRetryCount" -Value 0 -PropertyType "DWord"
            $status = "Success"
        }
        Catch
        {
            $status = "Failed"
        }
    }
}

Read-Host -Prompt "wait for enter"
```

Comment: Microsoft scripting guy has a blog that covers what you want to do: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/10/use-powershell-to-create-new-registry-keys-on-remote-systems/

Comment: @JamesC. and @Martin Brandl have provided some good links.A troubleshooting tip: you are looping over your list `$Computers` but the variable `$computer` is not used by the `New-ItemProperty` command. PowerShell will just execute the command on the localPC, and it will do it once for each `$computer` in `Computers`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Invoke-Command`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) cmdlet using the `-ComputerName` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. This working now.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web 

$Computers = Get-Content -Path 'G:\Shares\xxx\SebaTesty\computerlist.txt'

$results = foreach ($computer in $Computers) {
    If (test-connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Try {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock {
                New-ItemProperty -Path "hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" -Name "ArpRetryCount" -Value 0 -PropertyType "DWord"
            }
            $status = "Success"
        }
        Catch {
            $status = "Failed"
        }
    }
}
Read-Host -Prompt "wait for enter"
```